# CubePro Alternative Slicer

Tags: software, slicing, firmware, cubepro-duo

So, having bought this cube pro duo 3d printer a few days ago I have come to see how significantly limiting the default slicer software that comes with the machine is. For the prints that I am doing I've been looking around at alternative slicers however the cube pro has its own file format for builds and I'm not sure if any other software has the option to export those specifically and I also have no idea id the CubePro can read any files other than its own. On top of this whenever I download some other slicer it gets to the printer setup and there's a whole bunch of settings and parameters for the printer that I haven't been able to find, stuff like Firmware or Nozzle Diameter (Something that id expect to be easy to find).

In particularly a software called IdeaMaker is what I'm interested in since I've seen that you can make custom supports and that would be very useful for what I'm doing.

Does anyone know what I can do? Or is this a case of there's nothing I can do without some serious modification that I'd rather not do?

Any help is appreciated thanks! :D

Comment: The consequence of a 4000$ printer being locked down like that should be a refund.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, the CubePro 3D printers use their own format: .cubepro or .cubex.

It [appears](https://forum.simplify3d.com/viewtopic.php?t=5924) that a:

> .cubepro file format and found out that it only does a Blowfish ECB encryption of the .bfb file

This implies that you need to find a slicer that outputs `.bfb` tool path files (similar like G-code files) and a tool to encrypt the tool path file. The dubious CodeX tool and [this alternative](https://forum.simplify3d.com/viewtopic.php?t=5924) can do that for you.

Comment: It doesn't work on firmware version 2.00 in cube pro trio - any idea what to do ??

Comment: firmware version 1.10/V2 in cube pro trio is not working for me.  @baressa did you happen to find anything?